# Better/correct way to access included static information from inside of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my class:

```
class node:
    node.maxNum = 10000
    node.maxCoord = 10000.0

    def __init__(self, num = 0, **coordsIn):

        if num > node.maxNum: raise nodeNumException
        self.num = num

        ##set default args##
        coordsDefault = {'X' : float('NaN'), 'Y' : float('NaN')}

        ##set coordinates to input##
        self.coords = coordsIn

        @property.setter
        def coords(self, **Coords):
            for Key in Coords:
                if Coords[Key] > maxCoord: raise nodeCoordException
            ##Set _coords to default, then update from coordsIn##
            self._coords = coordsDefault.update(Coords)
        @property
        def coords(self):
            return self._coords
```

When creating an instance, the following error is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)
    File "C:\Projects\CANDE\mesh.py", line 7, in __init__
    if num > node.maxNum: raise nodeNumException
NameError: name 'maxNum' is not defined
```

I have tried accessing the `maxNum` and `maxCoord` variables inside of my class several different ways, but I cannot seem to figure out how to avoid this error.

Is there a way to fix my code and keep the same approach?

Also: is there a better way to do this? Any suggestions would be appreciated. This is my first major Python project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class node:
    maxNum = 10000
    maxCoord = 10000.0
```

Also change the line to  `if Coords[Key] > node.maxCoord: raise nodeCoordException`, using node to access.

Unrelated but you should use uppercase for class names: `class Node`

Comment: I swear that I thought tried that already MULTIPLE TIMES and it didn't work, but after exiting python session and coming back in, now it's working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just realized the problem: I updated my module, but had forgotten I needed re-import it. Instead of instancing the edited class I was just creating an instance of the same class definition over and over again. Argh.

Comment: well at least you figured it out eventually ;)

Answer (score 3):

Class Variables don't require a class qualifier when declaring/defining it. You only need the qualifier when accessing it

```
class node:
    maxNum = 10000
    maxCoord = 10000.0

    def __init__(self, num = 0, **coordsIn):

        if num > node.maxNum: raise nodeNumException
        self.num = num
        ........
```

You have more problems in your code

1. When defining the setter, you need  a property object.
2. The setter should always follow the getter or else you would get a NameError.

Comment: You should also probably use `self.maxNum` etc. instead of `node.maxNum` to access the class property inside of methods.

Comment: Technically, it's `maxNum` when using it at class scope, and `node.maxNum` when using it inside a method. Whether you are reading or setting the value is irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidSanders `self.maxNum` and `node.maxNum` are the same when reading the value, but very different if setting the value. Using `node.maxNum` for reading the value emphasizes that you are accessing a class variable, not an instance variable.

Comment: I think it needs to be `node.maxNum` because I am using it outside of the class in defining my exceptions before any instances are created. Also: thanks for hte help! I'll be accepting Padraic's answer is correct since his was first.

Comment: @chepner If you're only accessing the class attribute, you should be using `self.maxNum` unless you want to find and replace all lookups of that attribute when you change the name of the class.  If you really want to change the class attribute value, you should create a classmethod using `classmethod(some_method)` and invoke it by doing `self.some_method(new_value)`.

Comment: Class methods in Python are primarily intended as alternate constructors, and have very little to do with the choice between a class variable and an instance variable. There are valid reasons for accessing each type of variable from either a class method or an instance method.